# Can't make a cron Python script which uses Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, cron

I make a simple script (just to test) in Python which just make a void tkinter window

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

If I write `python3 kinter.py` in my terminal that's works okey, without problems.

The problem came with I put this same file in my `crontab -e` like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/francisco/Desktop/fcoterroba/personalProjects/myShit/kinter.py
```

This don't show nothing. If I read cron log:

```
Jun 15 16:44:01 mypc_fcoterroba CRON[125245]: (fcoterroba) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/francisco/Desktop/fcoterroba/personalProjects/myShit/kinter.py)
```

Do you know what can I do?

**BTW**: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Why would you want to create a Tk window using cron?

Comment: @ScottHunter The example is trival but what I really want to do is use a Tk window to notify the user that an action has just occurred

Comment: Cron jobs don't run in a terminal, so they can't use libraries that depend on user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Auto-answer**

If you want use TKinter or any other GUI Python's libraries, you should specify the display where you want to show it (which will usually be 0.0).
So, In mi case, I should have put this in the cronjob:

`env DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/python3 /home/francisco/Desktop/fcoterroba/personalProjects/myShit/kinter.py`